# How do you reference UI Event System from script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I tried creating a public variable and then referencing the EventSystem object from the Inspector of the gameObject the script is attached to, but whenever I try to access a variable from EventSystems,

I get a NullReference Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I tried finding it with `GameObject.Find()` but apparently I can't cast the `gameObject` to `EventSystem.EventSystem` with in-built cast.

I'm not sure what to do. I just want to access

`EventSystem.currentSelectedGameObject.name`

to find out which UI object in Canvas was selected.

Comment: I thought I had it by using `EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name` but I still get the same NullReference Exception...

Comment: Apparently `EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject` returns Null for everything. I guess that was the issue. I don't understand why it thinks I'm selecting nothing when I am clearly able to make my Scroll Rect object in the canvas to behave properly.

Comment: Resorted to `Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition)` and `Physics.Raycast()` to find the gameObject, since the EventSystem proved to be more complicated than expected.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you want, see documentation [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem-current.html).

```
EventSystem.current
```

[image]